# How to Reference an Interface Component in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I've got experience with Java in general, and other 'studio' packages like Visual Studio. However, I'm sort of stumped here.

I've got the following in my 'activity_setup.xml' file...

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fabPlayerToggle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="37dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="260dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    app:fabSize="mini"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />
```

I've successfully been able to generate toasts etc. using an onClick event, but I can't work out how to access properties of the FloatingActionButton, or other elements of the interface. I'd like to have something that functioned similarly to the following:

```
fabPlayerToggle = findViewById(R.id.fabPlayerToggle);
    fabPlayerToggle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (fabPlayerToggle.srcCompat == "@android:drawable/ic_input_add") {
                // Toggle to alternative icon and change visibility of other UI components
        }
    };
});
```

I'd then like to be able to reference other components, for instance my lblPlayer3Name, and change the visibility state / other attributes of that.

I'm sure this is something rather simple but I've just been totally flummoxed by it. Any and all help appreciated.

Comment: You want to access properties of Floating Action Button?

Comment: Yes, from within the main .java file.

Comment: Consider upvoting all the answers that help you and don't forget to accept the most helpful answer to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have already given an id to your FloatingActionButton

```
android:id="@+id/fabPlayerToggle"
```

So in your Java File create a FloatingActionButton object and reference it to the Button in the layout

```
FloatingActionButton myFab = (FloatingActionButton) myView.findViewById(R.id.myFAB);
```

So can now do many things in Java just as you did in XML

Examples:

```
myFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    public void onClick(View v) { 
        //Do Something on Click
    } 
});
```

To Make FAB invisible

```
myFab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

To Change srcCompact

Try Changing

```
app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
```

to

```
android:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
```

Comment: Sorry, I had that but didn't include it in my original post to prevent it being too verbose. Your 'setVisibility' worked when I tested it. Is there any dot operator that will get me the current srcCompat? I've tried .getsrc, getImage and others but none seem to be the correct. one.

Comment: Check the Updated answer

Answer (score 0):

If you use a unique OnClickListener for your FAB (FloatingActionButton), like this:

```
mFab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
mFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // view is your FAB
        // Cast it to a FAB, i.e., fab = (FloatingActionButton) view;
        //   or work with a member variable like I have done with mFab
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Burnt bread!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Now you have direct access to the FAB through `view` or standard means like member variables (`mFab` in my case.)

Comment: And if I wished to access the properties of a label or textarea when the FAB was clicked, how would that be done?

Comment: You can easy access those through [member variables.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html)

Comment: Right, I think you've helped me find what I was looking for. To make sure I'm understanding correctly, to access the member variables (that's the phrase I was after!) of a interface element X, you need: <type> <name> = findViewById(R.id.<name>); , and then you're able to retrieve members through methods such as <name>.getText() ?

Comment: If <name> is a member variable then yes.  If <name> is a `final` local variable then yes.  In other circumstances, probably no... things get a little confusing with inner classes.

Answer (score 0):

That actually are not propertirs. They exist only in the XML, which is converted into the views hierarchy during inflation. If you are interested in what happens to `app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"`, then:
`@android:drawable/ic_input_add` is a reference to the generated ID of a drawable resource file. During instantiation of `FloatingActionButton` the resource is loaded by the ID you have providede in the XML, and  is stored internally in the FloatingActionButton` object.

But it is not a property. `Java` has no property concept similar to C# for example. It uses so called setters and getters. So if you want to get some field from the class, you can *probably* get it using getters. But it might be not available at all.

Comment: Thanks for responding; that's unfortunate. I can't find any set or get methods that would return the image, so I might have to switch to using a standard button and updating the text value onClick.

Comment: @Nivarka, it is true that you can't get the `src` or `srcCompat` value, because it is not stored. It is converted to a `Drawable`. You **can** get the drawable by calling `fabPlayerToggle.getDrawable();`, but it will return a `Drawable` object. Can you tell me why do you want an `src` value? What do you want to do with it?

Comment: So, I want the button to act as a toggle between showing two additional text entry fields and hiding them. If when clicked the button's current icon is the one to 'show more fields', then set the visibility of the other fields to true, and change the button icon to a 'hide' icon. If the button is clicked and the 'hide' icon is showing... etc.

Comment: @Nivarka, then you can store a state sepatately in some field instead of checking it from the button.